# Open 443 port for ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, iptables

I have installed ssl certificate on nginx using certbot, I am able to access https://URL from browser only if i stop iptables, So I checked if 443 port was open

I created rule in iptables to open 80 and 443 ports:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

and checked  by nginx:

```
$netstat -anltp

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27432/nginx         
........... 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      27432/nginx
```

in mysite.conf file

```
 server {
       listen 443 ssl;
    }
```

and nginx

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and iptables..

```
 iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  133  9875 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53 
 3543  271K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
 1496  131K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:110 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:143 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995 
 2274 3696K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    1    56 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   45  2700 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:25 
   53  3288 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
  180 32695 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       58.218.204.189       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       58.218.204.189       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6686 packets, 10M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  133  9875 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 ctstate ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

but still I am getting connection refused in browser if iptables service is running, Nothing in nginx logs as it seems firewall issue.

nginx version: nginx/1.12.0
Centos 6, uname -a Linux server.name 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 11 17:13:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any help? thanks

Comment: Assuming you did a nginx reload after adding the ssl server directive.

Comment: yes i have done service nginx restart/reload

Comment: which distribution / version do you use? (iptables could be updated by firewalld)

Comment: Centos 6, uname -a
Linux server.name 2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 11 17:13:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I also included additional info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had issue with iptables I should have used -I instead of -A and SSL worked, as mentioned by Leader at [Let's Encrypt Community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/open-443-port-for-ssl/33716/3)